# A blocked external process in a swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, process, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

I am developing an encoder with java swing and ffmpeg.  I created a GUI interface in which I specify my inputs `(devices, frame rate, bitrate..)`. Then I call `ffmpeg` to encode and stream.

My problem is that the encoding class is well executed from a main class but it is blocked when called from the swing interface (specifically `jButtonactionperformed()`).

Can anyone help me?

here is my button action

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Encode s = new Encode();
    s.Encode(cmdLine);
}
```

and here is my encoding method

```
public void Encode(String cmdLine) {
    try {
        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
        //logProcessOutputAndErrors(p2); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ps: Cmdline is the command i collect from inputs

Comment: So, you want a tutorial on threads from us?

Comment: you should start the ffmpeg task in a separate thread to not block the ui thread.

Comment: in fact i execute the ffmpeg command in a seperate class but i call this class in the jButtonaction performed. @Jan Dvorak: i read about threads but i couldn't apply it. if you can explain it more please

Comment: here is my button action
  private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                
           Encode s= new Encode();
           s.Encode(cmdLine);   
         
    } 

and here is my encoding method
    public void Encode( String cmdLine) {       

        try {
           Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);            
           //logProcessOutputAndErrors(p2);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }

Ps: Cmdline is the command i collect from inputs

Comment: Any suggestions pleaase :(

Comment: 1) *"here is my button action"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14055818/edit) to the question. 2) If sticking with the `Process`, implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  3) Why not use jffmpeg and side-step the (more trouble, less control) `Process` altogether? 4) Add @clamp (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

First, you convert your Encode method into a Runnable class.

```
public class Encode implements Runnable {

    protected String    cmdLine;

    public Encode(String cmdLine) {
        this.cmdLine = cmdLine;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
            // logProcessOutputAndErrors(p2);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you instantiate the class as a Thread, and start it.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Encode s = new Encode(cmdLine);
    new Thread(s).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gilbert le Blanc. I copy and paste this but i have the same result. my streaming server receive my selected options(rate..) but the (Netstream.buffer.flush) until i close the interface. the process is no more blocked and ffmpeg start bufferfull etc.. :(

Comment: @user1932255: There's more to your problem then blocking the Event Dispatch Thread.  You have to get the audio buffer back to your GUI in some way, and let the GUI know that the buffer is complete.  I'm afraid that's more that can be dealt with on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The problem that when i execute the same code in a main class (not a GUI) it is fine and i get my streaming (buffer full) . that is why i thought about the event dispatch problem

Comment: The problem that when i execute the same code in a main class (not a GUI) it is fine and i get my streaming (buffer full) . that is why i thought about the event dispatch problem